# How can i wait for my call without using async on my ngOnInit method?

Tags: angular

I have the following code. To wait for my async call I am using the following

```
 testi() {
   return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
     resolve(true);
   })
  }


  async ngOnInit() {
    let pp = await this.testi();
    console.log('pp', pp);

}
```

is there any other way with which I can wait for the call here without adding `async` notation on my `ngOnInit` method?

Comment: Why don't you want to use async/await?

Comment: I want to use, but i don't want to annotate my lifecycle method with async

Comment: But why ? Angular supports `async` for `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: You can have a separated method that handles all the async parts, and within your `ngOnInit()` you just call that method.

Comment: @DanielGuzman i tried that but it does not work. Can you prrovide an example ?

Comment: What is your real problem ? Do you want to delay the component rendering until something has been loaded ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `then` instead of `await`:

```js
testi() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(true);
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.testi()
    .then(value => console.log(`pp: ${value}`))
}
```

If you are writing Typescript code, chances are that your compiled code will uses `then` instead of `await`. It is the "old" way of using promises.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

If you create a Promise inside `then`, you can return it to chain calls to `then` and avoid the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)):

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.testi()
    .then(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(`Hello ${value}`)))
    .then(value => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(`${value}!`)))
    .then(value => console.log(value));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to nest, you can return a promise and chain the calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separated method that handles all the async parts and its result, and within your ngOnInit() you just call that method.

```js
async testi() {
  let pp = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(true);
  })

  console.log('pp', pp)
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.testi();
}
```

Comment: how can i return pp from the `testi` ?

Comment: I'd suggest you use async/await, returning a promise and using then(), or returning an observable and subscribing to it.